# DrawingVisual .Drawing Hit performance

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

```
    /// <summary>
    /// To get the whole drwaing as a single DrawingVisual object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>DrawingVisual object</returns>
    public DrawingVisual GetAsVisual()
    {
      DrawingVisual vNewVisual = new DrawingVisual();

      using (DrawingContext vNewVisualsDrawingContext = vNewVisual.RenderOpen())
      {
        foreach (DrawingVisual vVisual in Children)
        {
          vNewVisualsDrawingContext.DrawDrawing(vVisual.Drawing);
        }
      }

      return vNewVisual;
    }
```

In my WPF application all drawing elements are kept as Drawing visual groups. When i exectue the same code in below two envirnments i am getting diffrent resuls as below.

In .Net 4.0 with Visualstudio 2010 - It works with considerable performance. The application gives almost high performance.

In .Net 4.0 with Visualstudio 2012 - It takes amost 10 times slower with previous one. What could have gone wrong?
Any clues?

Comment: `In .Net 4.0 with Visualstudio 2012` - Wrong. Visual Studio 2012 will install .Net FX 4.5 thus `replacing` the 4.0 assemblies.

Comment: so you mean it will compile the project with 4.5 platform even if we specify the target platform as 4.0?

Comment: .Net Framework 4.5 is an IN-PLACE update to .Net FX 4.0. Any machine that has 4.5 installed will run applications targeted to 4.0 using the 4.5 assemblies.